# I have two Interactive Report regions ( i.e Master & Detail h) . I want to refresh the Detail region whenever i click on master region

Tags: oracle-apex

I am working with Oracle Apex, I have two Interactive Report regions ( i.e Master and Detail having ID common in Both regions) . I want to refresh/Fill the Detail region whenever i click on any record in master region based on the common key ID. I think i cannot create master/ detail links declaratively between two reports. please guide the best possible way.

Actualy My first Report Region is MASTER and CHILD report region is DETAIL. And both REgions are on a Single Page

[My page with Both interactive Report REgions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEwJx.png)

Answer (score 1):

> please guide the best possible way.

The best possible way I can think of is to switch from Interactive Report to Interactive **Grid** as they, when put into master-detail relationship, do **exactly** what you asked for: refresh *detail* according to selected *master* record.

Comment: You are right - But as a starter i must have other options to choose for future development

Comment: That is a strange comment. Why do you need other options if this works and why would it matter if you're a starter or not ? Interactive Grid supports this functionality out of the box and interactive report does not, so... for a starter this is the best option.